# Send form to php script but hide the url

Tags: php, forms, post

Is it possible and also is it worth doing (security talking, as a extra step, of course not as the main security thing) to send a regular html form (not ajax) to a php script but to hide the scripts url?

So for example if i have:

```
<form action="http://example.com/phpscript" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

when the form is submited the user will be redirected to a succes page but not on the `http://example.com/phpscript` url (or maybe to this url but with some masking or some other ideas...).

Comment: It is totally not necessary if you have other appropriate security measures in place.

Comment: you, need to extra validation. Like only accept por, using request PHP vars to be sure from is called.

Comment: Why not using [URL rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) ?

Comment: didn't say not to. the question is: is it wise to do so. and why...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible unfortunately.
The best you could do is send it to your php page that takes care of your form then redirect with, ie :

`header("Location: index.php);`